# How to fix icon image missing when running SVG-EDIT on IIS7 localhost

Tags: javascript, iis, mime, svg-edit

Downloaded the latest version of SVG-EDIT from https://github.com/SVG-Edit/svgedit but getting a problem. All editing icons were missing when running it on localhost.

Debugged the page on Firefox and seemed the problem was caused by "$.getSvgIcon(...) is undefined"

Google search results in a hint that SVG's MIME type might not have been defined on IIS. It's still not clear to me how to fix it. Any idea?